# How to make Login Authentication in CodeIgniter for multiple user

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have not Idea Please help me

I will try to make Login Authentication  in CodeIgniter for multiple user its define role and its check on controller. But I want to make with helper.

Comment: please explain your question.

Comment: extend class, use library